# I need help to convert my kivy app to .exe

Tags: python, kivy, exe, kivymd

I've a great knowledge in python, now i'm practicing about python GUI,
I've choose KIVY for this purpose.
I've currently make an instabot in kivy, when i convert it into exe and run it, it crashes.
I need help help to run this
here's my code

```
import os, csv, pyautogui, sys
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path

class ScreenManagment(ScreenManager):
    pass


class SettingScreen(Screen):
    def SaveData(self):
        pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class InstaBot(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light" #Background color
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green" #Theme
        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS))
    InstaBot().run()
```

I can't upload functions because stacks alert there is more code in my question. I'm sorry.
My kivy file is

```
ScreenManagment:
    MainScreen:
    SettingScreen:


<MainScreen>:
name: 'main'
MDTextField:
    id: URL
    hint_text: 'Enter URL'
    pos_hint: {'x': .05, 'y': .89}
    size_hint_x: None
    width:'530'
    helper_text: 'Enter the URL of instagram id'
    helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
MDRectangleFlatButton:
    id: GetFollower
    text: 'GET FOLLOWERS'
    pos_hint: {'x': .77, 'y': .905}
    on_release: root.GetUsers()
MDTextField:
    id: UserId
    hint_text: 'User Id'
    pos_hint: {'x': .05, 'y': .79}
    size_hint_x: None
    width:'300'
    helper_text: 'Enter username you wanna add or delete'
    helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
MDRectangleFlatButton:
    id: AddNew
    text: 'Add New User'
    pos_hint: {'x': .05, 'y': .72}
    on_press: root.AddUser()
MDRectangleFlatButton:
    id: DeleteUser
    text: 'Delete User'
    pos_hint: {'x': .30, 'y': .72}
    on_press: root.DeleteUser()
ScrollView:
    size_hint: .43, .6
    pos_hint: {'x': .05, 'y': .1}
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (1,0,0,.5)
        Rectangle: 
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    MDList:
        id: list
MDRectangleFlatButton:
    text: 'Load records'
    pos_hint: {'x': .05, 'y': .03}
    on_press: root.LoadRecords()
MDRectangleFlatButton:
    text: 'Save records'
    pos_hint: {'x': .35, 'y': .03}
    on_press: root.SaveRecords()
MDTextField:
    id: msg
    multiline: True
    mode: 'rectangle'
    pos_hint: {'x': .55, 'y': .4}
    size_hint_x: None
    width:'300'
    max_height: '200'
    hint_text: 'Enter message'
MDRectangleFlatButton:
    id: SendMsg
    text: 'Send Message'
    pos_hint: {'x': .77, 'y': .3}
    on_press: root.SendMsg()
MDIconButton:
    icon: 'language-python'
    pos_hint: {'x': .925, 'y': .01}
    user_font_size: '30dp'
    theme_text_color: 'Custom'
    text_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
    on_release: 
        root.manager.current = 'setting'
        root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```

Comment: did you use pyinstaller to make exe file because this the recommended method from kivy
and what error appears in the console also can you post the spec file